# ezANOVA: access to aov content

Tags: r, bayesian, anova

I am using ezANOVA to calculate ANOVAs. I would like calculate a Bayesian measure, which makes use of the values returned in the aov object.
However, I have difficulties accessing the values that are returned in the aov object and consequently do not know how to address them in the function I use for the Bayesian measure. 
Let me give an example...

```
data("ANT") ## example data
rt_anova = ezANOVA(
  data = ANT[ANT$error==0,]
  , dv = rt
  , wid = subnum
  , within = .(cue,flank)
  , return_aov = T
)
rt_anova
```

We now get the following for the main effect of cue:

```
Stratum 2: subnum:cue

Terms:
                  cue Residuals
Sum of Squares  225485.61   8970.99
Deg. of Freedom         3        57
```

I now need to access the Degrees of Freedom as well as the Sums of Squares, but I currently have no clue how I must admit (they do not seem to accessible via something like

```
rt_anova$aov$........
```

Any suggestions are very welcome!

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `rt_anova$aov`, you'll see it is of class `aovlist`. (`class(rt_anova$aov)`).  Do some further exploration (`names(rt_anova$aov)`), and you can figure out what you need might be `rt_anova$aov$'subnum:cue'`

Comment: Thanks! I actually had tried `rt_anova$aov$'subnum:cue'` before, but still I am unable to find what I need there...:-/

Comment: what about `summary(rt_anova$aov$'subnum:cue')`?  Does that get you where you need to be?

Comment: Actually, like jeremycg said, the issue has been solved elsewhere and I do not really need the aov object ;-). Thanks for thinking about my question anyway!